# Credentials for connecting Azure SQL database to Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have connected Azure SQL database to Power BI within Azure portal:
[image]

I clicked on the `Get started` as shown in the screenshot and opened the pbids file downloaded.
but I'm not signed in within Power BI and it asked me to sign in again:
[image]

My Azure account(email address) is different from my Power BI email address, what credentials are required here? My Azure account info, Power BI account info or SQL database credentials?

Comment: Please select Database to connect to the Azure SQL database.

Comment: @LeonYue Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean, could you please be more specific? It's already connected to the database from what I see in Power BI, but Power BI would ask my credentials and I'm not sure what they are referring to

Comment: Hi @nilsinelabore, The left navigation: Database.

Comment: @LeonYue Do I have to fill up all 3 sections: Default or custom, Windows and Database or just Database?

Comment: No, you  only need choose one way, please choose Database to connect to the Azure SQL database.

Comment: Hi @nilsinelabore, sorry, I'm not familiar with DirectQuery,  Maybe you can ref it's document to get more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery. May I post it as asnwer?

Comment: @Leon Just realised in the bottom right hand corner it says `storage mode: DirectQuery`. Sure, thanks for the help:)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the left navigation: Database to connect to the Azure SQL database:

[image]

You don't have to fill up all 3 sections, just choose one of the ways.

And about your another question, Maybe you can ref it's document [How to connect using DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-use-directquery#how-to-connect-using-directquery) to get more details. You can choose the model:

[image]